# How to make es6 import/export works in Nightwatch test?

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I want to import into my test file utility module, which is written in ES6 and exports several things I need.  So what I do is

```
import { module } from 'file'
```

but it throws the 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token import' error.

I tried to:

1. add `require('babel-core/register')` to the top of the nightwatch.conf.js
2. add `require('babel-register')()` to the top of the nightwatch.conf.js
3. `npm i babel-plugin-add-module-exports --save-dev` ,  and add "add-module-exports" plugin to the .babelrc config file
4. `npm i babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev` , and add es2015 preset to the .babelrc config file
5. add

   ```
   require('babel-core')
   require('babel-loader')
   require('babel-plugin-add-module-exports')
   require('babel-polyfill')
   require('babel-preset-stage-2')
   require('babel-preset-es2015')
   ```

to the top of the nightwatch.conf.js

All this didn't help. What should I do to make import/export works?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Appears I was very close, the one thing missed from my attention:

I had

```
"presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ],
```

and { "modules": false } was the blocking thing. So, to make import/export works  you need:

1 At the top of nightwatch.config

```
require('babel-register')() // or require('babel-core/register')
```

2 .babelrc should contain

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
  ]
}
```

3 install babel

```
npm i babel-plugin-add-module-exports babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Comment: worked for me - just note that step (3) should also install `babel-core`

Comment: Thank you! +1 for the babel-core install note